# Clean up [exponent*] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

**tl;dr** I think we should re-tag [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent), [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential), [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation), [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents), and [exponential-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential-distribution) into [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential), [exponential-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential-distribution), and [exponential-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential-notation), which would involve automatically re-tagging the questions in [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) and manually re-tagging the questions in [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential) (265 questions).

**Full version** There are a number of similar-sounding tags that in my opinion need some reorganization:

- [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent): This has no tag wiki, but presumably deals with the mathematical concept of exponents, aka some number a raised to the power b. This tag has 193 questions and 0 followers.
- [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential): From the tag wiki, this can refer either to the mathematical function a^b, the general concept of exponential growth, the [exponential distribution from statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), or the [exponential notation used in text representations of floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) (E notation). This tag has 265 questions and 0 followers.
- [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation): This tag deals with anything related to the mathematical function a^b. This tag has 154 questions and 2 followers.
- [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents): This tag deals with the mathematical function a^b. This tag has 43 questions and 0 followers.
- [exponential-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential-distribution): This tag deals with the exponential distribution, an important distribution from stochastic processes. This tag has 25 questions and 0 followers.

I think the [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential) tag is particularly troublesome because it can be used to describe three different things (exponentiation, exponential distribution, and E notation), which goes against the "does it mean the same thing in all common contexts" [test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191). In my opinion there are really three distinct concepts across these five tags: the mathematical function a^b, the exponential distribution from statistics, and E notation for floats. Therefore I propose the following retagging:

- [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation): This tag would capture anything dealing with the mathematical function a^b, including the general concept of exponential growth, aka the function f(x) = b^x. In addition to the current questions in [exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation), I think we should fully re-tag [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) to this tag and also manually re-tag any questions from [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential) that deal with a^b or exponential growth. Making [exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents) synonyms of this tag could also make sense (they currently are not).
- [exponential-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential-distribution): This tag would capture anything dealing with the exponential distribution. In addition to the current questions in [exponential-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential-distribution), I think we should manually re-tag any questions in [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential) that deal with the exponential distribution.
- [exponential-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential-notation): This new tag would capture the E notation of floats. I think we should manually re-tag any question in [exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponential) that deals with E notation to this new tag.